# SpringBoot Kafka Throwing NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm trying to build a springboot microservice API to post the message to kafka on API call.
Kafka consumer has been connected through producer/consumer configuration correctly. But on calling the `sendToKafka` API, I'm getting the below error message

> [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sendToKafka"]

Below is the controller code

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/sendToKafka")
public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam(value = "message") String message) {
    System.out.println("sendMessageToKafkaTopic");
    producerService.sendMessage(message);
}
```

ProducerService

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println((String.format("$$$$ => Producing message: %s", message)));
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> listenableFuture = this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);
    listenableFuture.addCallback(listenableFutureCallback);
}
```

ConsumerService

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "sample", groupId = "group_id")
public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
   System.out.println((String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message)));
}
```

I'm using spring-kafka 2.6.6 version.
From the postman, Calling the API as below,

```
http://localhost:9001/KafkaApp/sendToKafka?message=Hi
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: sendToKafka is not a numerical value which can e parsed to an Integer. I think you passed a wrong value somewhere

Comment: sendToKafka is API call where the message to kafka is passed through @RequestParam(value = "message")

Comment: Yes, I get that, but it seems you are trying to convert that value to an Integer somewhere, as is stated in your error message: exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sendToKafka"

Comment: Understood. But from the code im not doing any data type conversion as you see from code Im just calling the Controller ->ProducerService .

Comment: yet somewhere, that is exactly what's happening. check the rest of the stacktrace to figure out where